# Horizontal Stackview in swift: how to wrap according content

Tags: swift, xcode

I use a stackview (horizontal) with this setup:
[image]

Inside it, I have just 3 buttons (without text, only icon). The height/width button are set by constraints:
[image]

And the result is:
[image]

BUT I don't understand why my second button has a huge width... even if it width is fixed at 44.

Have you got some explanations guys please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Distribution should be set to "Fill Equally", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings are just conflicting, that's the answer. It must fill stackview width with 3 buttons 44pt each + 6pt spacing between them, and this can't be resolved, because stackview width is bigger than 44*3 + 6*(3-1).

- If you want all buttons be on the left with 6 point spacing, then remove trailing constraint for stackview;
- if you want buttons to fill the full width -- then remove spacing = 6 and set distribution = equal spacing

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the distribution to equal spacing on the stack view. That means that the spacing will be equal between every button. If you do not have any constrains on the stack view that affects the width then that should work.

Otherwise you need to increment the spacing value in order for the buttons to have equal widths.

Thanks for the question!